# Want to cut right before second trailing slash?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cut

I wanted to cut the following rows right before second trailing slash.

Like

```
/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander/public_html/path/to/file/1
/home/testuser/public_html/path/to/file/1
/home/hellouser/public_html/path/to/file/13
```

TO

```
/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander
/home/testuser
/home/hellouser
```

How this can be done? using grep or cut or awk or sed? I am not sure.

Comment: `sed -r 's#(/[^/]*/[^/]*.*)#\1#' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk

```
awk -F/ '{print "/" $2 "/" $3}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Can you suggest a best tutorial url for beginners to learn awk.

Comment: This one is nice
http://www.lynda.com/Linux-tutorials/AWK-Essential-Training/162719-2.html

Comment: This is not a job for awk but if you did it in awk you wouldn't redundantly hard-code the FS between fields, nor would you hard-code a list of fields. To learn awk get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I agree, this is a quick and dirty way to go about this, but it still solves the problem. If there were requirements in the post about optimal efficiency, this clearly wouldn't be the answer.

Comment: A script that produces the desired output given some sample input is the starting point to identifying a solution. I expect that most people posting questions are very interested in how to do things the right way but don't know what the right way is or they wouldn't be asking the question and so they need us to tell them when a posted answer is doing things the wrong way even if it produces the expected output.

Comment: Here you can reuse the `FS`. `awk -F/ '{print FS $2 FS $3}'`

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below awk commands.

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print $1,$2,$3}' file
```

`BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}` at the BEGIN block, `/` was set as value of `FS` and `OFS`. comma on the print function prints the OFS value.

**OR**

```
awk -F/ '{print FS$2FS$3}' file
```

**OR**

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $1FS$2FS$3}' file
/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander
/home/testuser
/home/hellouser
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Can you suggest a best tutorial url for beginners to learn awk.

Answer (score 3):

This is the job `cut` was invented to do:

```
$ cut -d'/' -f1-3 file 
/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander
/home/testuser
/home/hellouser
```

There was a big clue in your question: "Want to **cut**..."

Comment: Thank you. You will find there's often a correlation between the name of the right tool to use and any basic operations you are trying to do. For example if you want to **find** files and then **sort** them and then see the lines at the **tail** of each and **tr**anslate some characters and con**cat**enate the result....

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F/ -vOFS="/"  'NF=3' file

/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander
/home/testuser
/home/hellouser
```

Comment: This site sucks, this is a terrible answer with no explanation, yet gets upvoted over ones that answer questions not asked thousands of times before with an explanation.

Comment: This will remove blank lines so you should use this:  `awk -F/ -v OFS="/"  '{NF=3}1' file`

Comment: Also, only some awks will recompile the record when you assign a value to NF. Some will require a subsequent assignment to a field while others still will just ignore it no matter what you do.

Comment: @EdMorton do you have examples of these awks ?

Comment: @Jotne There are no blank lines so i shouldn't use that and it wont remove blank lines it would replace them with `///`. Think before you comment with regurgitated `you should do this because` comments.

Comment: @JID - sure. nawk will require you to set `$1=$1` or similar after setting `NF=3` and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk will be unaffected no matter what you do with `NF` so none of the awks available on Solaris will behave as desired (since /bin/awk will, predictably, tell you it's a sytnax error!).

Comment: @EdMorton i dont really use solaris that much so i have never noticed. Thanks for the info i will be sure to keep it in mind in the future!